# HSP with bytestrings

Tags: haskell, happstack

I switched to [HSP](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HSP) in my home project - I like that it compiles to Haskell code. But my server uses ByteString for output. Is there a good way to make HSP generate ByteString output? As I can see output and the HSP' source code, there is hardcoded `"Any string literal" :: String` - explicit type qualification to String.

My point is that using lazy ByteString for concatenation is faster that String, and since input and output are ByteString there is no reason to have String just for templating.

Probably there is alternative to HSP?

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of `HSP` use the `text` package, which is more efficient than `String` but more correct than `ByteString`.